# SSRS Count on expression doesn't work on Matrix

Tags: reporting-services

I have setup a Matrix and use "Add total" to create a new column to show the total number in SSRS. Then I created another new column on the right with expression Replace the number in Add Total column with Text. However, when I use Count expression to count this new text column contain "Passed" and "Not Passed", it shows the total count without filtering.  I have tried different expression, it shows either the total count or 0.  I am getting confuse if I should be using =Count(Fields!xxx.Value = "Passed") OR =Count(Parameters!xxx.value = "Passed" ?

I have looked thru different example on this website but didn't seem to find a resolution, or it's the Matrix is created incorrectly ? Hope someone can provide some help. Million thanks.

Zoma

Comment: If you add a parent column group on the column with the "Passed" value, you could then filter on the column group and just count the values.

Comment: I would use a SUM with an IIF for the condition `=SUM(IIF(Fields!xxx.Value = "Passed", 1, 0))`

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tried =SUM but it returns with 0 when running the query, the Fields!xxx.Value I used on the SUM expression is a new calculated Fields I created contain expression, it's not the ordinary Field from the db.  Basically the Count or SUM expression I setup on "Passed" column is base on another expression.  Sorry, I am very new to SSRS, and I still get confuse with some feature and the relationship.  I hope I explained the problem clear enough. Thanks.